# How to determine the installed ColdFusion bitness

Tags: coldfusion

How can I determine if the installed ColdFusion server is 32 or 64 bit?

I would love to see an answer that solves my problem both from being logged in on the server and programmatically from CFML code.

Comment: Pretty sure it's contained in the Server scope? Also, will likely be somewhere on the "information" page in Administrator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, not quite as straight-forward as I thought, but the information is there.

### Programmatic Access

In all three CFML engines, you can programmatically access the JVM information via the server scope with `Server.Os.Arch`. This contains a value such as `amd64` for 64-bit, and `i386` or `x86` for 32-bit systems.

On Railo (but not ACF/OBD) there is also `Server.Os.ArchModel` which simply contains `64` or `32` as appropriate.

For all three engines you can get this 64/32 value with: `createObject('java','java.lang.System').getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")`

### Server Admin

In CF administrator, if you go to "Server Settings" > "Settings Summary" you can find the "Java VM Name" which contains `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM` (or equiv for 32 bit).

In OpenBD administrator, select "Server" > "System Info" and the third option contains "Operating System", which includes `amd64` on a 64-bit system, along with a link to "JVM properties", where you can find "java.vm.name" and "sun.arch.data.model" containing values for architecture name and bitness.

In Railo administrator, the "Overview" page (when you login) has an "Info" section which includes fields for both OS and JVM, each with either `64bit` or `32bit` after the version info.

Comment: Small clarification, `Server.Os.Arch` is not limited to *only* those two values. It could contain others like `x86`. (Side rant: For a property that refers to the jvm environ, not the operating system, "OS".arch was probably not the best choice of names on sun's part ;-)

Comment: Good point, Leigh. Just tried to find a list of all possible architectures, but not seeing anything. Possibly fair to say "anything ending in "64" is 64-bit, everything else is 32-bit?

Comment: I have not found an official list, but another thread mentioned [this entry](http://javablog.co.uk/2007/05/19/making-jni-cross-platform/) which lists some of the possibilities, including `x86_64` :/ (Fyi, the link is broken, so use cache or the waybackmachine.org to view it.)

Comment: Here is another [unofficial listing](http://lopica.sourceforge.net/os.html) that is a little more complete (though dated).

Comment: I need to figure this out as well but unfortunately my server won't start. Is this contained in a config file anywhere?

Comment: It's not a config setting, it's a system property.

If you have the installer you used on the server, the filename of that will identify if you used the 64/32 bit version. Or look in the CF webroot and the install log will likely tell you too.

Comment: CF10 just shows "Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM" for the 32 bit version and "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM" for the 64 bit version